# When using document.createElement to test that element’s scrollHeight and clientHeight, the values are always 0

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I’m trying to write a unit test for the following function:

```js
export function hasOverflowingContent({ clientWidth, clientHeight, scrollWidth, scrollHeight }) {
    return scrollHeight > clientHeight || scrollWidth > clientWidth;
}
```

This is my test:

```js
test('is overflowing', () => {
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    const child = document.createElement('div');

    parent.style.height = '200px';
    parent.style.overflowY = 'auto';
    child.style.height = '800px';

    parent.appendChild(child);

    document.body.appendChild(parent);

    expect(hasOverflowingContent(parent)).toBe(true);
});
```

For some reason when I `console.log(scrollHeight, clientHeight)` in the `hasOverflowingContent`
function the return is always `0, 0`. Why is that?

My testing toolchain consists of:

- jest@26.6.3
- @testing-library/react@11.2.3
- @testing-library/jest-dom@5.11.9

### Update

@connexo suggested wrapping the assertion in `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => { … })` to allow the “browser” to paint before checking the DOM. Implementing this did in fact result in a passing test:

```js
test('is not overflowing', () => {
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent.style.height = '200px';
    parent.style.overflowY = 'auto';

    const child = document.createElement('div');
    child.style.height = '100px';
    parent.appendChild(child);
    document.body.appendChild(parent);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        expect(hasOverflowingContent(parent)).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

… but it turns out it’s a false positive. If I change it to:

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
});
```

It still passes.

Comment: Your code is not awaiting the paint in the browser. Try to wrap your expectation in `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => { expect(hasOverflowingContent(parent)).toBe(true); })`. You might need to check the documentation of your testing framework to see how to support async expectations.

Comment: … aaaannnnddd it passed! Wanna add as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: The fact that it passed doesn't necessarily mean your test executed successfully. It might just mean that by the time `expect` ran, the test was already over. Please verify by testing an assertion that will definitely fail like `expect(false).toBe(true)` inside RAF. If it still passes, you need to check how to test async expectations with your testing framework.

Comment: You’re right. This passes: `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => { expect(true).toBe(false); });` :/

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question with these details then. Don't forget to explain what your testing toolchain looks like.

Comment: Updated the question with more detail.

Comment: I feel like that's the wrong unit test for that function. Why not keep it simple and pass a plain object during the test? Testing if the function works with actual DOM elements should be part of more complex integration test, where the function is used by some other component.

Comment: Interesting thought. Makes sense.